# Using ShowcaseView to target MenuItems Failed

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, showcaseview

I'm using https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView to display ShowcaseView for Menuitems as below:

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //Toolbar will now take on default actionbar characteristics
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setTitle("DDIT Results");

    try {

        new ShowcaseView.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .withMaterialShowcase()
                .setStyle(R.style.MyTheme)
                .setTarget(new ActionItemTarget(MainActivity.this, R.id.action_notify))
                .setContentTitle("Enable Notification")
                .setContentText("Click On the Button and get notified whenever the Result-table Changes")

                .build()
        .show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Which is causing the app to be crashed.

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_rateus" android:title="@string/rate_us" android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_notify" android:title="@string/notify" android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_none_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_privacy_policy" android:title="Privacy Policy" android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_email_us" android:title="@string/action_email_us" android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: insertShowcaseViewWithType cannot be used when the theme has no ActionBar
        at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.targets.ActionBarReflector.getHomeButton(ActionBarReflector.java:43)
        at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.targets.ActionBarReflector.getActionBarView(ActionBarReflector.java:36)
        at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.targets.ActionItemTarget.setUp(ActionItemTarget.java:49)
        at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.targets.ActionItemTarget.getPoint(ActionItemTarget.java:43)
        at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView$1.run(ShowcaseView.java:176)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Is it possible to have the showcaseview target the specific items in the action bar? I searched for this problem and didn't come up with any solutions.Hopefully, someone recognizes this error and has a quick answer for it - otherwise I can provide more information if requested.Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Ill suggest you to create custom action bar and than you can get the view on which you need to focus using showcase.

Comment: @VibhorChopra Can you provide sample code?

Comment: @Prabhakar- what you want, sample code of custom action bar or getting view and focusing on it using showcase?

Comment: @VibhorChopra  getting view and focusing on it using showcase.

Comment: @Prabhakar- Let me check if i get something

Comment: what is the crash? Can you please provide a log?

Comment: @AlexCurran I've edited the question with log contents.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a Activity class and implements it with OnClickListener.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ImageView menuDisplayIcon;
private ShowcaseView showCaseView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // For no title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // For ull screen view
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // Setting layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Initializing UI
    initUI();
    // Showcase
    showcaseUtils();

}

/**
 * Initializing UI components wrt MainActivity
 */
private void initUI() {
    menuDisplayIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuDisplayIcon);
}

/**
 * Showcase view
 */
private void showcaseUtils() {
    showCaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this).setTarget(new ViewTarget(menuDisplayIcon))
            .setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Description").setOnClickListener(this).build();
    showCaseView.setButtonText("Finish");
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (showCaseView != null) {
        showCaseView.hide();
    }
}
```

Step 2: Layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Step 3: Layout: actionbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:gravity="right">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menuDisplayIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/settingsicon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: Include Showcase SDk available on GitHub.

For any query feel free to ask.

Comment: It Works Except Two Things: 1) Finish Button is shown outside the range of display of phone 2) It doesn't adapt the custom theme

Comment: Are you trying on emulator?

Comment: No . Tried it on real devices.

Comment: I have checked the code it is coming right on my device.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, ShowcaseView doesn't support the latest version of AppCompat using an actionbar. You can see more details in this issue [here](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/issues/309).

My recommendation at the moment is to use an AppCompat activity with a Toolbar instead of the default ActionBar. This should work fine. There's a demo of this [as an Activity](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/sample/ActionItemsSampleActivity.java), and using a [Target](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/sample/ToolbarActionItemTarget.java)